# Append file date to css file in apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to find a way to make sure browsers dont cache versions of my css files everytime I push a new update.

I was thinking the best way would be to somehow get the file timestamp of the css file on the filesytem and append append it tot he css URL somehow like www.mysite.com/css/style.css?13245645434

Is this possible at all? If not, then any idea how i can make sure the browser gets a new version of the file when it is updated? I dont want to eliminate browser cache all together because if the file hasnt been touched then i would like it to be cached. However, when i push a new update i would like to someone tell the browser that.

I understand i can write server side code to put the style.css?2342343 in but i want to see if its possible through apache at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> everytime I push a new update

How do you push updates? If there is an automated build process you have then that is the right place to rewrite your URLs.

If you wanted to do the rewriting via apache you'd need a module which would parse the html and rewrite the links. That would not be optimal.

Lastly, consider rewriting to /css/42/style.css (where 42 is the current version) because in case you cache your site through a proxy or CDN, query parameters may not work.